# j2objc direct reference cannot be resolved ( with Maven structure /src/main/java )

Tags: java, objective-c, maven

I have to java classes Currency.java and Price.java
Price.java uses Currency.java and so has a reference to it.
I'm not able to convert two java classes where one is referring to the other one.
Which is the correct command syntax?

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:

If I use j2objc to convert Currency works fine.

```
j2objc --verbose -d objective-c -sourcepath src/path/to/the/package Currency.java
```

If I use j2objc to convert Price.java (with or without Currency.java) I get "Currency cannot be resolved"

```
terminal:
j2objc --verbose -d objective-c -sourcepath src/path/to/the/package Currency.java Price.java
translating Currency.java
time: read=0.005 compile=0.613 translate=0.222 write=0.077 total=0.917
translating Price.java
error: Price.java:39: Currency cannot be resolved
Translated 2 files: 1 errors, 0 warnings
```

I've tried also with the package wildcard * but I got the same problem:

```
j2objc --verbose -d objective-c -sourcepath src src/path/to/the/package/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the problem is related to the the src/main/java structure of Maven.

The following command WILL WORK

```
j2objc -d objective-c -sourcepath src/main/java com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Currency.java com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Price.java
```

while the following 2 commands will NOT WORK:

```
j2objc -d objective-c -sourcepath src src/main/java/com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Currency.java csrc/main/java/com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Price.java

j2objc -d objective-c src/main/java/com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Currency.java src/main/java/com/famenu/shared/model/menu/Price.java
```

this means that the -sourcepath option must be specified and MUST POINT to the path where the packages's directory structure starts (the directory that contains the folder com or org...).

Comment: You're welcome Pankaj! Up-vote an answer and/or a question if they were useful to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the plugin in eclipse? It save you an headache.

http://hsapkota.com.au/index.php/projects/20-j2objc-eclipse-plugin-howto

It's not perfect since they are no longer maintaining the code.

Comment: As described in my answer the problem is caused by the src/main/java folders used by Maven. Eclipse plugin has the same problem and it can't actually be used at all since it doesn't allow to specify the -sourcepath option and source files. :(

Comment: Actually you can: right click on project->properties-> expand J2Objc ->Classpath -> select your project's sources folder, should be the list item of the list.  Works like a charm :)